# How to implement a lazy stream chunk enumerator?

Tags: c#, stream, chunking

I'm trying to split a byte stream into chunks of increasing size.

The source stream contains an unknown number of bytes and is expensive to read. The output of the enumerator should be byte arrays of increasing size, starting at 8KB up to 1MB.

This is very simple to do by simply reading the whole stream, storing it in an array and taking the relevant pieces out. However, since the stream may be very large, reading it at once is unfeasible. Also, while performance is not the main concern, it is important to keep system load very low.

While implementing this I noticed that it's relatively difficult to keep the code short and maintainable. There are a few stream related issues to keep in mind, too (for instance, Stream.Read might not fill the buffer even though it succeeded).

I did not find any existing classes that help for my case, nor could I find something close on the net. How would you implement such a class?

Comment: Will you iterate through it more than once? Can the iterator return streams or does it need to return byte[]s? If it's streams, will they be completely read before you move on? If so, it'd be fairly easy to write an iterator to break up the source stream into smaller streams using only a small buffer. Alternatively, do you know the size of a chunk at the start, i.e. can you allocate a buffer and read the whole chunk in one go, or do you need to page through it to e.g. find the end marker?

Comment: @Rup: Iterates only once. Must be byte[]. The whole source stream is too large to be read completely, but the individual chunks will fit in memory. All chunk sizes and positions are known, but the actual length of the source stream is unknown (the final chunk is likely to be less than its supposed size).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<BufferWrapper> getBytes(Stream stream)
{
    List<int> bufferSizes = new List<int>() { 8192, 65536, 220160, 1048576 };
    int count = 0;
    int bufferSizePostion = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSizes[0]];
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        BufferWrapper nextResult = new BufferWrapper();
        nextResult.bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        nextResult.buffer = buffer;
        done = nextResult.bytesRead == 0;
        if (!done)
        {
            yield return nextResult;
            count++;
            if (count > 10 && bufferSizePostion < bufferSizes.Count)
            {
                count = 0;
                bufferSizePostion++;
                buffer = new byte[bufferSizes[bufferSizePostion]];
            }
        }
    }
}

public class BufferWrapper
{
    public byte[] buffer { get; set; }
    public int bytesRead { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously the logic for when to move up in buffer size, and how to choose what that size is could be altered.

Someone could also probably find a better way of handling the last buffer to be sent, as this isn't the most efficient way.

Comment: It just occured to me that you could make your own wrapper for a byte array that stores both a bytes array and an actual length (of real data) and return that every time.  It would mean that you wouldn't need to handle the array copy for the last partial buffer.

Comment: There is a bug at stream.Read: Read only signals EOF by returning 0 (not by bytesRead < buffer.Length).

Comment: +1, but why copy buffers? why not just return the buffer you read it into and always allocate a new one?

Comment: But that's easy enough to correct - retry the read to fill up the rest of the buffer until either the buffer is full or 0 bytes returned.

Comment: @Rup: Because the number of bytes read could be less, thus requiring a smaller buffer.

Comment: @Rup: Right. I was hallucinating excess bytes to be read but you can limit that very easily (buffer size minus existing size)

Comment: I fixed up a few things; incorporated my own comment and the fact that a partial buffer doesn't mean EOF.  There were also a few other bugs that I noticed and cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the implementation I currently use, already with improvements as per the answer by @Servy

```
private const int InitialBlockSize = 8 * 1024;
private const int MaximumBlockSize = 1024 * 1024;

private Stream _Stream;
private int _Size = InitialBlockSize;

public byte[] Current
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public bool MoveNext ()
{
    if (_Size < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    var buf = new byte[_Size];
    int count = 0;

    while (count < _Size) {
        int read = _Stream.Read (buf, count, _Size - count);

        if (read == 0) {
            break;
        }

        count += read;
    }

    if (count == _Size) {
        Current = buf;
        if (_Size <= MaximumBlockSize / 2) {
            _Size *= 2;
        }
    }
    else {
        Current = new byte[count];
        Array.Copy (buf, Current, count);
        _Size = -1;
    }

    return true;
}
```